# Mvvmcross: Binding menu items

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation-drawer, mvvmcross, navigationview

I am working on an Xamarin app that uses a `navigation drawer`. To fill the `navigation drawer` I used a **`NavigationView`**. Because I use Mvvmcross, and I also use **translation**, it would be easy if I can bind to the menu item. A**m I missing something or doesn't this feature exsist yet?**

This is the code I used and as you can see for the `nav_sync` **I tested it, and I don't get any text**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      local:headerLayout="@layout/navheadermain"
      local:menu="@menu/maindrawermenu" />
```

The MainDrawerMenu.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:title="Driver">
    <menu>
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_trackInService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_train_black_24dp"
        android:title="Track In Service" />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_trackOutOfOrder"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_train_black_24dp"
        android:title="Track Out Of Order" />
    </menu>
  </item>

  <item android:title="Technician">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_alerts"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_build_black_24dp"
      android:title="Alerts" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_trackAlerts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_build_black_24dp"
        android:title="Track alerts" />
  </item>
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
      android:title="Settings" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_sync"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync_black_24dp"
      local:MvxBind="Title Sync_Button_Label" />
  </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Doesn't exist yet

Comment: ok, I will look into it next weekend, and find out if I can add it in a fork then.

Comment: you need to translate your menu items in the c# code of your view